VRP Route Grouping
I am using nodejs to solve something on my taxi service project.
I have many inputs of addresses with postal codes, LAT/LNG, and want to group them in the nearest and same region first.
All of the addresses are under one country (SG).
I just tried myself some:
Approach 1
sort all addresses based on postal code and group them based on the first 2 postal digits.
problem:
this approach makes some nearest regions put in one group because of different postal codes.
**
Approach 2**
Sort addresses based on postal code and then calculate all distances with geolibs lib,  start from the first address find the nearest address within 1000 meters and group it if no nearest address increase the meter to +1000 to max 5000.
problem:
It is some sort of ok but it is also based on the order of input. Sometimes if the same address is placed end of the list input, it does not group up to the nearest or existing group.
Approach 3
using Google distance matrix & clustering.
problem:
not getting better results.
